# How to count unique words in string and output line where they occur? C++

Tags: c++, string

So I'm working on this homework assignment and I'm really having trouble. I'm supposed to count the number of words more than two characters(have to contain one letter), unique words, and the number of times each unique word appears in the Programming Execution Environment. I'm also supposed to get input to search for in the PEE and output the number of times it appears and the line where it appears. I have some of it working, but I'm really struggling with counting how many times each word appears. I know my code is really bad right now, but that's why I'm here. I'm really struggling with these string functions for some reason. Any help is really appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

//PEE string
string envstr("");

bool checkChar(unsigned c)
{
    return (ispunct(c) || isspace(c) || isblank(c) || isdigit(c) || c == '\n');
}

void searchWord(unsigned c, size_t length)
{
    multiset<string> words;
    vector<string> vwrds; //this was something i was trying out
    string tempword;
    while (!checkChar(envstr[c]) && c < length)
    {
        tempword = tempword + envstr[c]; //problem here
        c++;
    }

    tempword = tempword + " ";
    vwrds.push_back(tempword); 

    words.insert(tempword); //this is just a bunch of random letters

    tempword.clear();
    //for (multiset<string>::const_iterator i(words.begin()), end(words.end()); i != end; i++)
        //cout << *i;
}

bool checkIfWord(char c)
{
    bool valid = false;
    int i;

        for (i = c; i > c - 2; i--)
        {
            if (!checkChar(envstr[i]))
                valid = true;
        }

        if (valid)
            searchWord(i, envstr.length());

    return valid;
}

int main()
{
    //this code given by my instructor
    extern char **environ; // needed to access your execution environment

    int k = 0;
    size_t wordCount = 0;
    while (environ[k] != NULL)
    {
        cout << environ[k] << endl;     
        string str(environ[k]);
        envstr = envstr + str;
        k++;
    }

    //iterator to count words
    wordCount = count_if(envstr.begin(), envstr.end(), checkIfWord);

    cout << "\nThe PEE contains " << wordCount << " words. \n";

    //transform environment string to lowercase
    transform(envstr.begin(), envstr.end(), envstr.begin(), tolower);

    string input;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter your search item: \n";
        cin >> input;
        //string can only be forty characters
        if (input.length() > 40 || input == "\n")
        {
            cout << "That search query is too long. \n";
            continue;
        }

        //change the search string to lowercase, like the envstr
        transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), tolower);

        int j = 0;
        int searchCount = 0;
        vector<size_t> positions;
        size_t pos = envstr.find(input, 0);

        //search for that string
        while (pos != string::npos)
        {
            positions.push_back(pos);
            pos = envstr.find(input, pos + 1);
            searchCount++;
        }

        cout << "\nThat phrase occurs a total of " << searchCount << " times.\n";
        cout << "It occurs in the following lines: \n";
        //output where that string occurs
        for (vector<size_t>::iterator it = positions.begin(); it != positions.end(); ++it)
        {
            for (int i = *it; i < envstr.length() - 1 && checkChar(envstr[i]); i++)
            {
                cout << envstr[i];
            }

            cout << endl;
        }

        positions.clear();

    } while (input != "END");

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please describe a sample input, what happens when your program runs on that input, and exactly what you think should have happened instead.

Comment: Instead of using a multiset, why not use a map<string,int> where the int-value in each key/value pair represents the number of times you've seen that particular word?

Comment: Here's a sample input: 
c:\temp\temp\Good;
d:\Dos\temp;
e:\Windows!
The expected output should look like the following:
temp: 3 counts, Good: 1 count, Dos: 1 count, Windows: 1 count, Total number of words: 6, Total number of unique words: 4.
@Jeremy, I tried to use a map for this, but I ran into problems because my code isn't separating the words properly. How can I make that work?

Answer (score 1):

First, your function `checkChar()` returns false when the parameter is a char, so if you want to print where that string occurs, it should be:

```
for (int i = *it; (i < envstr.length() - 1) && !checkChar(envstr[i]); i++)
{
    cout << envstr[i];
}
```

Second, the code for counting words makes no sense and there is a potential out-of-bounds here: `if (!checkChar(envstr[i]))`, I would suggest you to split the string using delimter '\', then do something.